# Description about the set of quadratic integer with prime norm.

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-integer-rings

I have a guess that, if $p$ is a prime number, then
$$ \text{if }\exists a\in\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{k}] \text{ such that } N(a)=p,
\\ \text{ then }\left\{z\in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{k}]:N(z)=p\right\}= \left\{  a,\overline{a}  \right\}\cdot \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{k}]^*  $$
In short, all the element with norm $p$ is actually associated with $a$ or $\overline{a}$, where  $\overline{a}$ means $a$'s conjugate.
Is it true?
(I seems have proved this for cases of $k\equiv2,3 (\text{mod } 4)$, while the case for  $k\equiv1 (\text{mod } 4)$ seems rather complicated)

Comment: What is $k$? $\quad$

Comment: k is a square-free integer.

Comment: So...by $\mathbb Z[k]$ did you mean $\mathbb Z[\sqrt k]$?

Comment: Oh no, mistake of typing... Sorry, I'll rewrite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $d > 1$ be a squarefree positive integer, and let $R=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$.

Fix a prime $p$.

Suppose $a\in R$ is such that $N(a)=p$, and let $\overline{a}$ denote the conjugate of $a$.

**Claim:**$\;$If $b\in R$ is such that $N(b)=p$, then either $b/a$ or 
$b/\overline{a}$ is an element of $R$ (and hence is a unit of $R$).

**Proof:**

Assume the hypothesis.

Then we get
$$
\left\lbrace
\begin{align*}
\frac{b}{a}&=\frac{b\overline{a}}{p}\\[4pt]
\frac{b}{\overline{a}}&=\frac{ba}{p}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
\right.
$$
Wrting $ba=g_0+g_1\sqrt{d}$ and $b\overline{a}=h_0+h_1\sqrt{d}$, our goal is to show that either $g_0,g_1$ are both divisible by $p$, or $h_0,h_1$ are both divisible by $p$.

Write $a=x+y\sqrt{k}$ and $b=u+v\sqrt{k}$.

Expanding $ba$ yields
$$
\left\lbrace
\begin{align*}
g_0&=ux+vdy\\[4pt]
g_1&=vx+uy\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
\right.
$$
and expanding $b\overline{a}$ yields
$$
\left\lbrace
\begin{align*}
h_0&=ux-vdy\\[4pt]
h_1&=vx-uy\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
\right.
$$
Then we have
\begin{align*}
g_1h_1
&=
(vx+uy)(vx-uy)
\\[4pt]
&=
v^2x^2-u^2y^2
\\[4pt]
&=
v^2(p+dy^2)-(p+dv^2)y^2
\\[4pt]
&=
p(v^2-y^2)
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
so $p{\,\mid\,}g_1$ or $p{\,\mid\,}h_1$.

Without loss of generality, we can assume $p{\,\mid\,}g_1$ (the case $p{\,\mid\,}h_1$ is analagous).

Then we get
$$
g_0^2-dg_1^2=N(ba)=N(b)N(a)=p^2
$$
hence from $p{\,\mid\,}g_1$, we get $p{\,\mid\,}g_0$.

Thus $g_0,g_1$ are both divisible by $p$, which completes the proof.